# Using BIT datatype to filter a query in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I'm building a stored procedure that uses a bit parameter.
this bit parameter is used to filter the email column.

if @param is 1 - show all clients that has an email.

if @param is 0 - show all clients without an email.

and if @param is null (not passed to the procedure) - show both clients with and without an email.

that not going so well. any any suggestion?

```
where case @email when 1 then email is not null
                 when 0 then email is null)
```

Comment: The suggestion from lad2025 is probably the way I would go. It is worth mentioning that this is taking on the appearance of a "catch all" type of query which can have some serious performance challenges. You might take a peek at this article for some ways to combat those challenges. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Note that you use `@param` first and then use `@email` in your code example. Try to use good variable names, like `@HasEmail`.

Comment: Thanks sean! I'll take a look at the article

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple `OR`:

```
WHERE (@param IS NULL)
   OR (@param = 1 AND email IS NOT NULL)
   OR (@param = 0 AND email IS NULL)
```